# Неверный источник/канал трафика в Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Всем привет!
Возникает такая проблема. Когда смотришь источник/канал трафика в GA4 в них иногда попадаются страницы платежных шлюзов или 3-D Secure. Это негативно сказывается на рекламных компаниях, т.к. непонятно к какому реальному источнику принадлежит эта конверсия.
Есть ли способ как то исправить это дело?

P.S.-Скорее всего такая ситуация возникает из-за того, что страницы платежных шлюзов и 3-D Secure находятся не в домене сайта. Сейчас эта проблема уже решается, но есть ли еще какие-то способы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось в статье ниже:
https://osipenkov.ru/unwanted-referrals-ga4/

Можно добавить любой источник в список нежелательных переходов.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)